# php echo with ajax javascript. And url contains string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I used a JavaScript code in php mysql that worked perfectly with string inside and without problems.

But now I try to add it in JavaScript, ajax so that it is not changing the page when you send the data to another php page. Everything works unless ajax does not recognize the strings. What am I doing wrong?

```
        echo"
    <td><a href='#' onclick='myBorrar". $id ."()' class='sidebar-link' title='Borrar'><i class='mdi mdi-server-remove'></i></a></td>
  </tr>   



<script>
function myBorrar". $id ."(){

  var r = confirm('Estas seguro que queres borar? Todos los datos se van a perder!');
  if (r == true) {


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'eliminar-status.php?id=". $id ."&submenu=". $submenu ."&menu=". $menu ."&producto=". $producto2 ."' ,
                data: { id: 'liviudiaconu' },
                success : function() { 

                    // here is the code that will run on client side after running clear.php on server

                    // function below reloads current page
                    location.reload();

                }
            });

  } else {

  }

}
</script>

  ";
```

If I change ajax to href it works without problems with string.

And ajax works, it's calling the php sub-page, but it doesn't recognize the string.

Comment: `location.reload()` reloads the page.

Comment: what does this have to do with the strings that don't recognize them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending the `id` parameter twice. You have `id=". $id` in the URL, and

```
data: { id: 'liviudiaconu' },
```

The second parameter is taking precedence, so the script doesn't get the correct ID.

Get rid of the `data:` option.

Comment: yes ... is work fine , after deleted data.  thanks.